# I need to print the old and sorted list but I am encountering an error

Tags: haskell

I need help in coding this because I keep getting this error:
practice.hs:44:40: error: parse error on input `='
|
44 |     sortedList :: [Integer] sortedList = sort numList
|

I hope someone can help. Here is my source code

````
import Data.List

listBuilder :: IO()
listBuilder = do
    numList []

main = do
    listBuilder
    putStrLn "Enter 5 Numbers"
    num1 <- getLine
    num2 <- getLine
    num3 <- getLine
    num4 <- getLine
    num5 <- getLine
    
    num1 :: numList
    num2 :: numList
    num3 :: numList
    num4 :: numList
    num5 :: numList
    sortedList :: [Integer] sortedList = sort numList
    print ("Old List: " ++ numList)
    print ("Sorted List: " ++ sortedList)```
````

Comment: What is `num1 :: numList` supposed to do?

Comment: put the value of num1 in the list, numList

Comment: but `::` means "has type". Furthermore you can not alter a variable: variables are immutable.

Comment: you can construct a list with `let numList = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5] :: [Integer]`.

Comment: how can I append those values to the numList??

Comment: you don't. You simply create a list with `num1`, `num2`, etc.

Comment: How can i sort the list then into ascending order?

Comment: by using `let other_list = sort numList`, then `other_list` will be the sorted variant of `numList`.

Comment: What source are you using to learn Haskell? It is not doing a good job.

Comment: many online sources. data is overflowing in my mind right now. please drop some good sources to learn from

Answer (score 1):

First off, there are no "variables" in Haskell - values are immutable!
Secondly, `:: Something` is a *type annotation*, so `num1 :: numList` would mean "num1 is of type numList" - but what is "numList" supposed to be?

Here is a very simple solution:

```
import Data.List

main = do
    putStrLn "Enter 5 Numbers"
    
    line1 <- getLine
    let num1 = read line1 :: Int

    line2 <- getLine
    let num2 = read line2 :: Int

    line3 <- getLine
    let num3 = read line3 :: Int

    line4 <- getLine
    let num4 = read line4 :: Int

    line5 <- getLine
    let num5 = read line5 :: Int

    let list = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5]
    let sortedList = sort list 

    putStr "Old List: "
    print list

    putStr "Sorted List: "
    print sortedList
```

OK, so I read a line from standard in, using [getLine](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:getLine). This has type `IO String`, so it is an IO action that yields a String.

Using [read](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read), which has type `Read a => String -> a`, we turn the String into an Int. The type means "some 'a' which has an instance of typeclass Read, take a string and spit out an 'a', if possible".
I'm using a type annotation `:: Int` to signal, that I want that `a` to be an `Int`.

Repeating that 5 times, I end up with 5 Ints.
I create a [list](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists) using the `[]` list constructor (note: you can use `:` [read "cons"] to put an element *to the front of the linked list*).

[sort](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sort) from Data.List will sort the list in ascending order, using the `compare` operation. (There is also [sortOn](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortOn), so you can provide a function to sort the elements by).

Then I use [`putStr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:putStr) to print my string (without a newline).
The [print](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:print) function takes an `a` and calls `show` on it, to turn it into a string, before printing it. So you don't need to use `print` with strings (you can use `putStrLn` (newline at end) or `putStr` (no newline)).

This is getting into advanced territory, but the solution is not elegant and we can do better!
Basically, we want to repeat the same IO action 5 times and convert a list of strings to a list of Ints:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Monad

main = do
    putStrLn "Enter 5 Numbers"
    
    inputs <- replicateM 5 getLine
    let list = map read inputs :: [Int]
    let sortedList = sort list 

    putStr "Old List: "
    print list

    putStr "Sorted List: "
    print sortedList
```

[repeatM](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM) repeats a *monadic action* n times.
The `<-` means something like "take this value out of the monadic context, so `IO [String]` and we want the `[String]` part.

`map` just applies the provided function (here `read`) to every element of the list argument.
I'm using a type annotation again, to tell Haskell, that the result of this expression should be a list of Ints (otherwise `read` would not know what `a` is supposed to be).

Comment: You're welcome. http://learnyouahaskell.com is not a perfect resource, but for the very basics it is good and very approachable.
You can find more resources here: https://github.com/bitemyapp/learnhaskell

Comment: @AEric. pls don't forget to accept the answer (click checkmark), if it solved your problem. cheers